# Unable to get FBNativeAd Test Ad working in our iOS App

Tags: ios, facebook-audience-network

We have an iOS App (SWIFT 4) where we want to integrate Facebook Audience Network for Native Ad. Following the instructions at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/ios (EXCEPT for entering "Payment info" in our Facebook Business account as we are in development phase still), https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/ios-native and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/testing#testing-testAd our code (in ViewController viewDidLoad()) to load a TEST AD is as follows:

```
  let nativeAd = FBNativeAd(placementID: "IMG_16_9_LINK#" + "OUR_PLACEMENT_ID" )     
  nativeAd.delegate = self
  nativeAd.mediaCachePolicy = FBNativeAdsCachePolicy.all
  nativeAd.load()
```

But FBNativeAdDelegate callback does not fire.

```
func nativeAdDidLoad(_ nativeAd: FBNativeAd) {
   ...
}
```

Using Facebook -> Manage Property -> Property Settings -> Ad Request Debugger, there is no request reaching the Server for reasons unknown. In our App "info.plist" file "App Transport Security" has property "Allow Arbitrary Loads" enabled (YES) just in case.

We have tried both Simulator on Mac as well as iPhone/iPad where Facebook App was logged in as the SAME user with the Business Account matching OUR_PLACEMENT_ID.

Any help to resolve the mystery will be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It started working after set Key **NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsForMedia** to YES under **App Transport Security** in Info.plist! Note that this key will have to be manually added as it is not available as a default in XCode editor.

How I wish Facebook had **clear** documentation on this which would've saved 2 days of wasted effort!